# Page redirects to subdomain folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code that redirects a user when they sign out:

```
   if (IsRequestedPage("Login") && Authorization.IsAuthenticated())
            {
                Response.Redirect("CalendarView.aspx");
            }
            else if (LibKezberProjectManager.Data.Context.NeedsFirstUse() && !IsRequestedPage("FirstUse"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("FirstUse.aspx");
            }
            else if (!Authorization.IsAuthenticated() && !IsRequestedPage("Login") && !LibKezberProjectManager.Data.Context.NeedsFirstUse())
            {
                string fileName = this.Page.Request.Url.ToString();
                fileName = fileName.Remove(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?redirect=" + fileName);
            }
        }
        public bool IsRequestedPage(string pageName)
        {
            return Request.RawUrl.Contains(pageName + ".aspx");
        }



protected void lnkSignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Authorization.Logout();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?logout=true");
}
```

When I sign out, in some pages, instead of bringing me to:

```
kezblu.mysite.com/Login.aspx?logout=true
```

I end up at:

```
kezblu.mysite.com/kezblu/Login.aspx?logout=true
```

I have no way to debug this locally... I do not have an IIS Server.

What might cause this?

It should always redirect to kezblu.mysite.com/Destination.aspx

I do not have any code that appends the subdomain directory.

Thanks

Comment: Milo, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?logout=true")` instead?

The `~/` prefix corresponds to the root of your web application.

Comment: So that will ensure I do not get kezblu.site.com/kezblu/blah.aspx

Comment: @Milo: Do you have any pages inside a subfolder named "kezblu"?

Comment: Doing that seems to cause the /kezblu to always appear, not what I want.

Comment: Yes, all my pages are in that subfolder because that is supposed to be the folder where I put all my subdomain content...

Comment: Do you think the fact I can do:
kezblu.mysite.com/Page.aspx and kezblu.mysite.com/kezblu/Page.aspx means my subdomain was incorrectly set up?

Comment: @Milo Not the subdomain, but the server.

Comment: Okay, so asp should be reporting my root as kezblu.mysite.com Ill contact them.